# How to automate logging into Wifi network

Tags: macos

My university wifi network redirects me to a login page where I have to enter username and password. Is there any way to automate it in mac osx or via a browser addon?

Comment: Every time you open the browser? Or once every time you connect to the network?

Comment: anything is good enough

Comment: Perhaps you could look at the form code on the login page and use some sort of automated request with the right `POST` content.

Answer (score 2):

There are password vaults/form fillers out there, something like [1Password](https://agilebits.com/onepassword/mac/features) would probably do the job for you.

If you want to script it yourself, there is a ruby based browser automation tool called [Watir](http://watir.com/). [iMacros](http://www.iopus.com/imacros/) is a similar concept.

OSX's built in [Automator](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2488) and [Applescript](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptX/AppleScriptX.html) can probably be setup fairly easily to do that as well. You can have a look at [Fake](http://fakeapp.com/) if you want a pre-built browser solution for automation using those two tools.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Fake](http://fakeapp.com/). It's an OS X application that lets you automated things in web pages. Should be pretty easy to automate a simple login.